# Solve this Linear Circuit

Tags: linear

Consider these relations about that circuit bellow:

$$i_2 = i_L\\
V_2 = V_L\\
Z_2 = Z_L$$[image]

As reference the circuits below on pictures I and II, is correct to affirm that the value of Voltage $V_x$ can be calculated by this equation:

$$\frac{V_x-V_0}{R_0} - I_0 + \frac{V_x}{R_1} = 0$$

Answer: **Correct**.

PS.: I try every relations with nodes Law, KCL and KVL but there are too many equation but not visualize that especific equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is basically saying that in Figure 2, V<sub>x</sub> and R<sub>x</sub> are the *Thevenin equivalent* of everything in Figure 1 except the load Z<sub>L</sub>.

To work out the Thevenin equivalent of a source network, you need to know the open circuit voltage and the short circuit current. In fact, since the question only asks about V<sub>x</sub>, in this case you really only to need to work out the open circuit voltage.

To do that, just imagine in Figure 1, that Z<sub>L</sub> is removed and replaced with an open circuit, and work out the voltage V<sub>L</sub>. Since you have two independent sources, you'll use the *superposition principle* to do that.

Comment: Definitely solve my problem. Thank you so much. When I visualized the Thevenin model on Figure 2, it was perfectly clear! (just voltage source) VL' = R1.V0/(R1+R0) and (just current source) VL'' = R1.R0.I0/(R1+R0), finally, by superposition principle Vx = VL = VL'+VL''. Additionally Rx = Rth = R0//R1.